# How to check if a cookie is present in order to allow the user to continue an image?

Tags: php, .htaccess, session, cookies

I need to restrict access to profile images only to logged in users. I've been [reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342509/get-php-session-vars-in-htaccess) [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990337/how-to-protect-against-direct-access-to-images) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13658988/prevent-direct-access-to-images-using-the-browser-url) [about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963284/restrict-access-to-image-files-for-logged-in-users-only-in-php) [how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400154/deny-all-allow-only-one-ip-through-htaccess) to do that, but didn't find examples that let me understand how to do it. Maybe I just didn't understand because I don't know much about .htaccess rules.

I've tried:

```
order allow, deny
deny from all
```

But it denies access to all (dóh), including myself. I cannot use IP addresses.

I don't use sessions ID's in the URLs, but I check for the logged in users with a php script (the same that generates the session in the first place, when the user logs in).

**So I thought that maybe I could implement a cookie check?**

I'm not using cookies at the moment, but I could create a cookie every time the user logs in, and destroy it when the user logs out. So my questions are:

**Is the cookie-check a safe enough, performant option?**

**If it is, how may I do that check?**

I've come so far to understand this:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

 # search for image files
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$
 # look for my cookie
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.mycookie.$ [NC]
```

**How to check if the cookie is present then allow to continue to the image?**

Please note that the images are shown embedded in my site inside each profile .php file.

Thank for your help!

Comment: why a -1 vote without an explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `$_SESSION` array, you can create a session using `session_start()` and destroy it using `session_destroy()` it is easier to validate session than cookies.
You can also send parameters when creating a session, for example

```
$parameters = array('param1' => 'value', 'param2' => 'value2' /* paramN => valueN*/);
session_start($parameters);
```

and validate it like this

```
if(isset($_SESSION)){
//Do stuff
}
```

you can also check if an specific parameter is in the session

```
if(isset($_SESSION['param1'])){
//Do another thing
}
```